# Jquery Slides plugin how to fade

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I need to fade content rather than scroll. How can I acheive this. I'm sure it's possible...http://slidesjs.com/

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slides({
    effect: 'fade'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marco. Right in fornt of my eyes yet I missed it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use the built in .fadeOut, .fadeIn

```
$(element).fadeOut()
```